# glsmLoadTextureLevelBuffer make double memory use when drawElement

Tags: ios, memory, opengl-es

I create a texture from a 1024x1024 png file (gfxAllocateTextureLevel),
But when I draw this texture by drawElement,
The memeory become double because the call of  glsmLoadTextureLevelBuffer!!!

---

Nicol Bolas,Sorry,I don't know!

```
0 libSystem.B.dylib malloc<br/>
1 libGLProgrammability.dylib glsmLoadTextureLevelBuffer<br/>
2 libGLProgrammability.dylib glsmLoadTextureStructure<br/>
3 GLRendererFloat gldLoadCurrentTexture<br/>
4 GLRendererFloat gldUpdateDispatch<br/>
5 GLEngine gleDoDrawDispatchCore<br/>
6 GLEngine glDrawElements_IMM_Exec<br/>
7 OpenGLES glDrawElements<br/>
```

This is the track, I think glTexImage2D  malloc some memory , and malloc some memory again for cache when draw it at the first time, Could someone know what is the process?!

Comment: Seems it is internal, implementation-depended routine. It may the the case, where the implementation is temporarily storing two copies of texture: one in "CPU" memory (for user, for updates, etc) and one on "Graphics" memory (to be locked during rendering). Usually eating double memory is a tradeoff for not flushing the pipeline on texture update.